# Program tabs on taskbar/panel were accidently removed (Cinnamon)

Tags: debian, cinnamon, panel

I'm using Debian 10 with Cinnamon, and I accidentally deleted the open program tabs that are normally on the panel. I did this by right clicking the panel>Modify panel>Remove panel.
The panel/taskbar, however, still exists (menu and applets are still there on the panel), it's just the program tabs that go on the panel have disappeared.

Anyone know how to get program tab visibility back? Adding a new panel doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to locate anything resembling "Add to Panel">"Window list", which is what most people were saying. However, to get the currently running program tabs on the panel, you can restore panel setting: **right click the panel>Troubleshoot>Restore all settings to default**.

This brought back the tabs/windows onto my panel, which allowed me to minimize running programs once more. It also got rid of my desktop background, and I still don't have a designated minimize button on any of my open windows (I have to right click and select "minimize" to do that). At least I can see them on the panel though! What a silly mess.